# Meteor Helper not working with if statement

Tags: if-statement, meteor, helper

I'll try to clarify this as much as possible because I believe the answer is going to be something very simple I'm overlooking.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="profile-info active"><a href="#">Personal Info</a></li>
    <li class="profile-groups"><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
    <li class="profile-commitments"><a href="#">Commitments</a></li>
</ul>
```

My Helper:

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
'personal':function(){
    if ($('.profile-info').hasClass('active')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

I just want 'personal' to return TRUE. However it always returns false no matter what type of "IF" statement I give it.

Comment: Because it is run when the template is rendering and your HTML is not yet attached to DOM. Therefore, the jQuery selector does not pick it up, and the result is empty.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. Do you know how I can delay it properly?

Comment: Don't. That's not the way things are done in Meteor. DOM reflects state, not the other way around. Look at my answer to your other post and see the way it flows.

Comment: I don't see where you use the helper `personal`. And that is important to answer the question. Suppose you would use the personal helper right after your navtab, then the template was not finished rendering and no element with class .profile-info is in the DOM.

Comment: Hm.... I see you asked a similar question but with more code and explanation and even an answer :)